# In Angular Kendo Grid How to ensure auto Fit Column

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am working on Angular version of Kendo Grid, how to ensure Kendo Grid column width is auto set meaning each column take its full width as it needed. I not worried about record column but I want to make sure header column display complete text without worrying width of div is in and I can do parent div overflow-x.

Because I am using column dynamically so text will be different each time and I cannot set like following;

```
<kendo-grid-column field="activeState" width="280" title="Active Status">
 </kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [autoFitColumn](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-autofitcolumn) or [autoFitColumns](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-autofitcolumns) methods:

[DOCS + EXAMPLE](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/resizing/#toc-auto-fitting-content)